# Return result from other activity to map activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker, start-activity

I have two activities : `MapActiviy` and `DetailsActivity`.

I used an intent and startActivityForResult, it works but not what I want?
now when I start the app, it goes to Detailsactivity, and when I press back button in the phone, it return
the correct result and show MapActiviy, but what I want is that:

1. start app,
2. get result from Detailsactivity without pressing or
   clicking any button (like something happen in backgroud where the user don't know)
3. the app should start and show MapActiviy at first time, the result should show,
4. if we click the marker on `MapActivity` the `DetailsActivity` should
   start agin because there are other data that I want to see in this activity

please note that, I used `finsh()`; `onBackPressed()`.. in `DetailsActivity` and I got the correct result on map
and the app start as I want in the map activity but when I press marker, it won't let me go to `Detailsactivity` again? because
when go there again it will find finsh() function and end this activity stright away?
Also I use intent after `finish()` to start `MapActivity` again but this keeping loop and make it worse?
if I don't use finsh(); onBackPressed().. and comment them out, the app start in `DetailsActivity`
and when press back button it work as should be (when press back button) it go to map, get result, allow me to click on marker, and go to `DetailsActivity` again, but I want the app start on map, get result on map by some how from Detailsactivity without click
anything, allow to click on marker to go to `DetailsActivity`.

DetailsActivity:

```
Intent data = new Intent(Detailsactivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                        // Intent intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(MapsActivity.class));
                        // Intent data = new Intent();
                        String value= "LOW";
                        data.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, value);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                        data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
                        //  finish();
                        // onBackPressed();
                       // moveTaskToBack(true);
               //startActivity(data);
```

MapActiviy:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // First we need to check if the requestCode matches the one we used.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE) {

            // The resultCode is set by the DetailActivity
            // By convention RESULT_OK means that whatever
            // DetailActivity did was executed successfully
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the result from the returned Intent
                String result = data.getStringExtra(Detailsactivity.EXTRA_DATA);

                // Use the data - in this case, display it in a Toast.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               // String a = result;

              //  String a = String.valueOf(result);

                if (result.equals("LOW") ){

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(station1,20));

                }

            }


            else {
                // setResult wasn't successfully executed by DetailActivity
                // Due to some error or flow of control. No data to retrieve.
            }


        }
```

Comment: I better format the question. However, we need to be clearer. There is a lot of text for a question that could be asked more simply.

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, just I explain everything to be clear! for a simple explanation, my app start on DetailsActivity, but I want it start in MapActivity, and get result from DetailsActivity without pressing anything, in same time I have marker on map when I press it, it should go to DetailsActivity. The code work but I have to press back button and when the app start it shows DetailsActivity

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you want to launch ```MapActivity``` upon starting the app, make sure that this is tagged as your launcher activity on your manifest. Then you can call your ```DetailsActivity``` intent on your marker click listener.